# What editions of Windows Server 2008 support print server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, print-server

Client is creating a server that will be running our website and dual purposed to act as a print server.

We're trying to determine if Server 2008 Web Edition supports being a print server, however the comparison chart I found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-differentiated-features.aspx) only mentions Internet Print Client.

Unfortunately I work at a software company, so no one knows, and Microsoft's feature comparison isn't being incredibly helpful.

**If Web Edition does not support Print Server, what is the recommended edition for a Web and Print server machine?**

Comment: Why not just buy a hardware print server?  I think I paid about $80 for a wireless one.

Comment: Unfortunately not our decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Edition does **not** support sharing of printers. It can have printers itself, but **cannot share** them either to a local network or across the Internet.

See the note on this [TechNet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779133(WS.10).aspx)

All other Editions support Print Sharing.
Standard Edition support everything the Enterprise and Datacenter Editions support. 
Small Business Edition support that as well, but there's limitations to consider with SBE. 
Foundation also support sharing printers, but there are even more limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and subsequent search I have found that Foundation Server is capable of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The possible workaround vector might be a program that accepts e.g. PostScript emulating e.g. JetDirect protocol and then prints it locally (folks asked me if it can be solved; haven't seen one yet)